# How can you have odd nuclear spin angular momentum but positive parity or vice versa?

Tags: particle-physics

How does it happen that you can get states like $J^\pi=3^+$ or $J^\pi=2^-$? I think this could be because $\pi=(-1)^l$ so you could have an even state in $l$ but the $J=l+s$ sum could be an odd number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is essentially correct.
If you want to think about the nucleus in a shell-model sort of way, you can say that
the nuclear spin $J$ is the vector sum of the spins $S_i$ and orbital angular momenta $L_i$ of all the nucleons in the nucleus.

In the [deuteron](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153422/44126), for instance, the nucleus must be antisymmetric under exchange of the "identical" proton and neutron.  In that special case we know from the non-existence of the stable diproton or dineutron that the deuteron has isospin zero, and therefore unit spin. In order to have positive parity, the deuteron wavefunction must have even $L$. (And experimentally, the deuteron is mostly $s$-wave, though there's a $d$-wave component due to the tensor part of the nuclear force.)

There are a few places in the chart of nuclides where you can look at the spin-parities of adjacent isotopes and ascribe them to the motion of the "extra" particle.  For example, lithium-6 is $1^+$, and lithium-7 is $3/2^-$: you can say that the "extra" neutron has $L=1$. Or compare oxygen-16, $0^+$, to oxygen-17, $5/2^+$: that's consistent with the extra neutron having $L=2$. In large or non-magic nuclei, though, the many-body interaction is usually too complicated to make simple statements like that.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are talking about mesons.

First of all, parity is not (-1)^L for a meson, it is (-1)^(L+1). This is because you have to take into account the fermion-antifermion relative parity for the quark-antiquark pair, which is negative.

Secondly, yes, it is L that matters and not J (which includes S). Thus, the low-lying mesons (pi, rho, D, D*, Upsilon, etc.) all have L=0 and hence negative parity. Among them, the pseudo-scalars are S=0, while the vector mesons are S=1.