# Matrix element of two nucleon interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, matrix-elements

I have a couple of questions regarding the following problem:

Let the interaction between two nucleons given by: $\hat{V}_{1,2}=\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{(1)}\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{(2)}$.

What I need help with is the following: Evaluate the following two-body matrix element in the coupled base:
$$<l_1s_1l_2s_2;LS;JM_J|\hat{V}_{1,2}|l_1s_1l_2s_2;LS;JM_J>$$
being the angular momentum couplings: $\mathbf{J=L+S}$ with $\mathbf{L=l_1+l_2}$ and $\mathbf{S=s_1+s_2}$.

Now, what I have so far is:
$$\hat{V}_{1,2}=\hat{\sigma}_x^{(1)}\hat{\sigma}_x^{(2)}+\hat{\sigma}_y^{(1)}\hat{\sigma}_y^{(2)}+\hat{\sigma}_z^{(1)}\hat{\sigma}_z^{(2)}$$
which I think only affects the coordinates $m_{s_1}$ and $m_{s_2}$, since the $\sigma$'s are the Pauli matrices and the states are $<s_1=1/2,m_{s_1}=1/2>=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $<s_1=1/2,m_{s_1}=-1/2>=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, but these coordinates ($m_{s_i}$) don't appear explicitly on the matrix element, so I don't know how the operator should act.

On the other hand, I know the only bound state is the proton-neutron pair, which has $J^{\pi}=1^+$, so the only possibilities are $S=1,L=0(\implies J=1)$ and $S=1,L=2(\implies J=1,2,3)$. This I guess implies the state $|l_1s_1l_2s_2;LS;JM_J>$ should be decomposed into two possible states, but I don't know how to do that, or how the operator $\hat{V}_{1,2}$ will act on the state in the end.

My first guess is that $\hat{V}_{1,2}$ doesn't affect the coordinates $l_1,s_1,l_2,s_2,L,S,J,M_J$ so that would mean the matrix element is 1, but I suppose that is not correct.

Could anyone help me on getting the concepts clear?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/688678/which-of-the-two-possible-orientations-of-parallel-spins-is-favoured-by-nucleon).

Comment: How does that post answer the questions posed above?

Comment: It parses out the method. You need to clarify the question; it appears, but fails to be stated, that it concerns the deuteron.

Comment: I edited the question. What I need to do is evaluate the matrix element. The question only talks about two nucleons, but I inferred it had to be the deuteron since it’s the only nucleon-nucleon bound state, right?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your possibly malformed question, but, ignoring the gaps, I rush to review basic facts,
$$\hat{V}_{1,2}=\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{(1)}\cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma}^{(2)}= 
\tfrac{1}{2}\left ((\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{(1)}+\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{(2)})^2-\boldsymbol{(\sigma}^{(1)})^2-(\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{(2)})^2  \right).$$
Note this has the wrong sign w.r.t. the standard interaction in the link provided to the question, so your statement on its significance is discounted.

- Assuming you are talking about the [deuteron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterium#Approximated_wavefunction_of_the_deuteron), the r.h.s. evaluates to
  $\tfrac{1}{2}(4\cdot 2 -3-3)=1$ for *S*=1, *L*=0, *J*=1, i.e., the $^3S_1$ parallel-spin ground state, isosinglet;
- or else, $\tfrac{1}{2}(-3-3)=-3$ for *S*=0, *L*=1, *J*=1,  of lower energy *in this unconventional flipped sign potential*, for $^1P_1$.

In more detail, $\mathbf{S=s_1+s_2}$, where $\mathbf{s_1}=\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{(1)}/2,$ etc, and $\mathbf{S}^2=S(S+1)$, yielding the above standard resolution.

So, you see your matrix element *only* depends on *S*, as *L* and *J* are completely blind to this "potential", as evaluated above.

(It looks like a homework problem to me, but perhaps there are unacknowledged dimensions here...)